# Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog - Rubymine

Tags: api, rubymine, pivotaltracker

As of yesterday when trying to integrate Pivotal Tracker tasks with Rubymine (6.x and now 7 EAP) this error appears instead of Rubymine connecting to the Tracker server -

`Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog`

Anyone else getting this / thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This was an api key error. Unfortunately not a very helpful error message from RubyMine.